# Select subset of unique patient ID

Tags: r

I have a dataset of 19000. The lenght of the unique patient ID's is 15000.
I want to have a subset of these unique ID's, but with the other variables as in the orginal dataset

```
patnr      age    and 25 other variables
1          20
2          21
3          16
4           5
19000
```

How can i do this? Now i can only see how many unique patient ID's are in this database with this command:

```
length(unique(data$patnr))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: If `patnr` is duplicated, which one do you want to keep in the results?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your data.frame is called, df. You can use `unique` as follows to select the first instance of a patient ID appearing:

```
dfUnique <- df[unique(df$patn), ]
```

Note that this will drop roughly 4,000 rows and you would lose that information if the other variables are different for the same patient in the second observation.